# Watchdog Soft Lockup Error in tty4 with no GUI access

Tags: grub2, nvidia, xubuntu

I have installed some NVIDIA driver my DELL laptop on Ubuntu 18.04 in order to work with GPU. When I rebooted, a black screen appeared after showing "Unbuntu . . . . " for 2 seconds. I can't do anaything on this black screen. However when I hold "ctrl + alt + F4", I can access to 'tty4' on which I can login and access to a terminal (in which I can browse directories etc.). However after 10sec or less, I'm getting the 'Watchdog Soft Lockup CPU" error. It doesn't let me do what I want in the tty4 terminal. And this error loops forever.
I tried to fix this by :

1. access to grub menu, then hold 'E' letter, and change params' grub. I added at the end of the line starting with "linux" : nouveaumodeset=0   . When I restart, the problem still the same.
   2)I edited via tty4's terminal the file : /etc/default/grub , line 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash". I replaced "quiet splash" with "nouveaumodeset=0". When rebooting, nothing change.

Any idea to fix this error ? . I'm blocked with it since 1 week.

thank you in advance

Comment: What "some" Nvidia driver did you install?

Comment: the Nvidia driver was in the cuda installator (.sh) that I got from Cuda website. I think it was a Cuda 11.2